# Jquery Radio Button for Search Filter

Tags: jquery, html

Can someone help me here...Am thinking of using a feature found at http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/UIElements/SearchBox/ but it uses checkbox instead of radio. I want the dropdown to show 4 radio buttons and the user should be able to select just one option. I tried a variety of options and it does not work. I will be using the latest jquery -- 1.8

I tried using prop, attr and read the forum but of no help. Your knowledge would be much appreciated.

My html is below

```
    <div class="content">
        <h1>UI Elements</h1>
        <div class="box">
            <h2>Search Box with Filter Demo</h2>
            <form id="ui_element" class="sb_wrapper">
                <p>
                    <span class="sb_down"></span>
                    <input class="sb_input" type="text"/>
                    <input class="sb_search" type="submit" value=""/>
                </p>
                <ul class="sb_dropdown" style="display:none;">
                    <li class="sb_filter">Filter your search</li>
                    <li><input type="radio"/><label for="all"><strong>All Categories</strong></label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio"/><label for="Automotive">Automotive</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio"/><label for="Baby">Baby</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio"/><label for="Beauty">Beautys</label></li>

                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
```

and original script is below --

```
        $(function() {
            /**
            * the element
            */
            var $ui         = $('#ui_element');

            /**
            * on focus and on click display the dropdown, 
            * and change the arrow image
            */
            $ui.find('.sb_input').bind('focus click',function(){
                $ui.find('.sb_down')
                   .addClass('sb_up')
                   .removeClass('sb_down')
                   .andSelf()
                   .find('.sb_dropdown')
                   .show();
            });

            /**
            * on mouse leave hide the dropdown, 
            * and change the arrow image
            */
            $ui.bind('mouseleave',function(){
                $ui.find('.sb_up')
                   .addClass('sb_down')
                   .removeClass('sb_up')
                   .andSelf()
                   .find('.sb_dropdown')
                   .hide();
            });

            /**
            * selecting all checkboxes
            */
            $ui.find('.sb_dropdown').find('label[for="all"]').prev().bind('click',function(){
                $(this).parent().siblings().find(':checkbox').attr('checked',this.checked).attr('disabled',this.checked);
            });
        });
```

Comment: what is it you achieved ? are there any errors or the functionality is not working?
What is the problem

Comment: @Raghurocks, the name attribute weren't set.

Comment: Ya I saw that, then atleast more radio buttons should be selected no @gdoron , what is the problem op is facing I am not clear with that.

Comment: Atleast did he get that output or some sort of errors @gdoron

Comment: Thank you all. 
Raghurocks -- All the radio buttons were being selected.
gdoron -- You saved my day..thank you so much.
Have a great christmas and great new year....
Another weird problem...does anyone know why <form> gets closed prematurely.

View source shows the above html code and firebug shows
            <h2>Search Box with Filter Demo</h2>
            **<form id="ui_element" class="sb_wrapper"></form>**
<p>
                    <span class="sb_down"></span>
                    <input class="sb_input" type="text"/>
This whole div inside a <td>

Comment: If answer resolved your problem mark as answered so that it will be useful for future viewers

Comment: Raghurocks..forgive me but how do I mark as answered....?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give all the radios the same name so only one of them could be selected.

```
<input name="foo" type="radio" />
<input name="foo" type="radio" />
<input name="foo" type="radio" />
<input name="foo" type="radio" />
```